# OpenUI5 compatibility for a .net developer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sapui5

Im a .net developer, looking for learning SAP OpenUI5 as most of our clients are into SAP. Please suggest options for getting skilled in SAP OpenUI5 or if there is an alternative tool which can be used in Visual studio and easily integrated with SAP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://open.sap.com/, there are a many sufficient courses for UI 5. The Walktrough is also very educational:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html

As ide you can either use eclipse or the recently available WebIDE.

Must-have websites are:

- http://openui5.org/
- https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com
- https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html